# Multiple images in one attachment page

Tags: images, attachments

I want multiple images for one post attachment page, but there is no option for that. How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An attachment page is dedicated to a single attachment media item (image, video, audio etc.). You can change it's behaviour by editing `single-attachment.php`. However this is not recommended.

It is possible to create galleries and insert them in posts. Or install a [plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=gallery) that displays custom posts as galleries of images.